# how to write to stdin in a TLS-enabled docker using the python docker API?

Tags: docker

I'm using a TLS-based docker using the python API.

I want to write to standard input (stdin) similarly to:

```
echo ls | docker run --rm -i gliderlabs/alpine sh
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One has to get the underlying socket, and call the appropriate methods `sendall` and `recv` as follows.

```py
# one needs to start the container first, and it is not possible to start the shell directly
# because methoed "run" does not support returning a socket
# one also needs to detach it otherwise the container waits synchronously for the end of the command
# calling "sleep" works, it is actually good because it means that the container will timeout if something goes bad
container = client.containers.run("gliderlabs/alpine", command= "sleep 100", detach = True)
# now we call the shell
# note that we don't set tty=True otherwise one gets the shell invite
socket = container.exec_run(cmd="sh", stdin=True, socket = True)
# we set the timeout in order not to be blocked afterwards with blocking read
socket.socket.settimeout(1)
# note that os.write does not work
# because it does not TLS-encrypt
# one must use "sendall" instead
socket.sendall(b"ls\n")

# a read block after a send
try:
    unknown_byte=socket.recv(1)
    while 1:
        # note that os.read does not work
        # because it does not TLS-decrypt
        # but returns the low-level encrypted data
        # one must use "socket.recv" instead
        data = socket.recv(16384)
        if not data: break
        print(data.decode('utf8'))
except so.timeout: pass

socket.sendall(b"exit\n")
```

Comment: This shouldn't work. The socket recvs 8 bytes of header describing the channel (stdout, stderr) and length of what is to be received next, trying to decode that will likely fail